# ASP.NET MVC disable dropdownlist on page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and jQuery to achieve this.

What I'm trying to do is to disable or enable a dropdownlist based on if a checkbox is checked or not.

I can get this working, however I can't seem to disable the dropdownlist on pageload. the statement is executed, but the element is not disabled.

What I think the problem is, is that the check is performed, BEFORE the dropdownlist (from the viewmodel) is populated, and the data somehow overrides?

Here's my HTML:

```
<p>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.RoomRequired, new { id= "room-required" })
    <label>Room Required</label>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Room Options</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OptionId, new SelectList(Model.RoomOptions, "Id", "Name"), "Select option", new { id="option-select })
</p>
```

and fixed Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#room-required').change(function () {
     $('#option-select').prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });

    $('#room-required').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: >> What I think the problem is, is that the check is performed, BEFORE the data (from the viewmodel) is loaded into the page, and de data somehow overrides the attribute?

This is not a reason, data loaded from viewmodels on server side but javascript works on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorta of solved the problem. For some reason, jQuery was re-enabling the dropdownlist. I had to add a javascript script to the HTML page itself and trigger the change event in there.
I know it's not the best solution, but it's a workaround that works for me.

Answer (score 3):

`.prop()` is preferred for changing the `disabled` property, and you can pass it a boolean, so your code could be simplified to:

```
$('#option-select').prop('disabled', $('#room-required').is(':checked'));
```

Or full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#room-required').change(function () {
         $('#option-select').prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });

    $('#room-required').trigger('change');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lk5B/1/)

Comment: That's a much cleaner solution, thanks! Also lol at myself for writing another if/else statement, while I could just trigger the event. But unfortunately, this hasn't solved the problem; the dropdownlist is still enabled on pageload.

Comment: As you can see from the fiddle, the code in the answer is OK, so that means there must be something going on elsewhere on the page causing the problem, maybe a syntax error somewhere. Try refreshing the page with the console open (F12) and watch for any errors.

Comment: No errors, but the difference with your fiddle and my application is that my dropdownlist is generated and populated by razor with data from the viewmodel.

Comment: That itself shouldn't make a difference because razor will be outputting a dropdown and so as far as jQuery is concerned there's no difference other than any other elements/code on the page. I would suggest doing View>Source in the browser so you get the final HTML, save it as a `.html` doc, and then bit by bit start removing things until all that's left is the dropdown and the code in answer.  As you remove bits, re-test the page each time to see if it starts working. I appreciate this could take a while but it should lead you to the problem eventually.

Comment: First of all, double check that your dropdown and checkbox have the correct IDs. If you have a public URL I will take a look.

Comment: I didn't have time to break down the whole view (it's pretty big), but I found in Firefox that, when the page loads the dropdownlist is disabled momentarily, but then enabled again. I've also looked at the id's and they're exactly the same. I've also found I cannot disable the dropdownlist by adding @disabled = "disabled" directly into the razor statement, which is pretty weird.

Comment: That sounds like some other code is re-enabling the dropdown. Using Chrome Dev Tools I would put a breakpoint at the trigger call, and then step through each line of code from there until you see it get re-enabled, that should lead you to the offending line.

Answer (score 0):

What `attr()` does is assigns the value in the second parameter to the specified attribute of the HTML element. We want `<input disabled="disabled" />` and not `<input disabled="true" />`.

So, use -

```
$('#option-select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

instead of -

```
$('#option-select').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

Comment: That didn't make a difference, both 'true' and 'disabled' work, but the dropdown still isn't disabled on load.